# finding a relationship between two sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles

> Given a triangle ABC, let $B'$ and $C'$ be points on the sides AB and AC such that $BB' = CC'$. Let $O$ and $O'$ be the circumcentres (i.e. the centre of the circumscribed circle) of triangles ABC and $AB'C'$, respectively.Suppose $OO'$ intersect lines $AB'$ and $AC'$ at $B''$ and $C''$, respectively. If $AB = 1/2 AC$, then
>
> A) $AB'' < 1/2 AC''$
> B) $AB'' = 1/2 AC''$
> C) $1/2 AC'' < AB'' < AC''$
> D) $AB'' = AC''$
> E) $AB'' > AC''$

Since we have circumscribed circles, I dropped down perpendiculars from $O'$ and $O$ to sides $AB$ (and $AB'$) and $AC$ (and $AC'$) so that I have right triangles. Also, I know that perpendiculars should divide the side of the triangle in half (so a perpendicular from $O'$ to side $AB'$ would bisect $AB'$, for example. But I'm not sure what to do after that.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let 
\begin{align} 
|BB'|&=|CC'|=u
,\\
\angle BAC&=\alpha
,\quad
\angle CBA=\beta
,\quad
\angle ACB=\gamma
,\\
|AB|&=c,\quad |AC|=b=2c
,\quad |BC|=a
\\
|AB'|&=c-u,\quad |AC'|=b-u=2c-u
,\quad |B'C'|=a'
,\\
\sin\beta&=2\sin\gamma
,\\
|OA|=|OB|=|OC|&=R
=\frac{c}{2\sin\gamma}
,\\
M_b&=\tfrac12(A+C)
,\\
M_b'&=\tfrac12(A+C')
,\\
|AO'|=|CO'|&=R'
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\angle COA&=2\beta
,\\
\angle COM_b&=\beta
,\\
\angle ACO
=\angle OAC
&=\tfrac\pi2-\beta
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
a&=
c\sqrt{5-4\cos\alpha}
,\\
R&=\frac{c\sqrt{5-4\cos\alpha}}{2\sin\alpha}
,\\
|OM_b|&=R\sin\angle ACO
=R\cos\beta
\\
&=
\frac{c\sqrt{5-4\cos\alpha}}{2\sin\alpha}
\cdot
\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}
\\
&=
\frac{c\sqrt{5-4\cos\alpha}}{2\sin\alpha}
\cdot
\frac{c^2(5-4\cos\alpha)+c^2-4c^2}{2c^2\sqrt{5-4\cos\alpha}}
\\
|OM_b|&=\frac{c(1-2\cos\alpha)}{2\sin\alpha}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
a'&=\sqrt{b'^2+c'^2-2b'c'\cos\alpha}
\\
&=
\sqrt{5c^2-6cu+2u^2-2(2c-u)(c-u)\cos\alpha}
,\\
R'&=\frac{a'}{2\sin\alpha}
,\\
|O'M_b'|^2&=R'^2-|M_b'C'|^2
=\frac{a'^2}{4\sin^2\alpha}
-
(c-\tfrac12u)^2
\\
&=
\frac{((2c-u)\cos\alpha+u-c)^2}{4\sin^2\alpha}
,\\
|O'M_b'|&=
\frac{c-u-(2c-u)\cos\alpha}{2\sin\alpha}
.
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\tan\angle OC''C
&=
\frac{|OM_b|-|O'M_b'|}{|AM_b|-|AM_b'|}
=
\frac{
\frac{\tfrac12(1-\cos\alpha)\,u}{\sin\alpha}
}{\tfrac12u}
\\
&=
\frac{1-\cos\alpha}{\sin\alpha}
=\tan\tfrac\alpha2
.
\end{align}

Hence, in $\triangle AB''C''$
we have
\begin{align} 
\angle C''AB''&=\pi-\alpha
,\\
\angle B''C''A&=\tfrac\alpha2
,\\
\angle AB''C''&=\pi
-(\pi-\alpha+\tfrac\alpha2)
=\tfrac\alpha2
,
\end{align}

hence, $|AB''|=|AC''|$
and the answer is "D".